# Searching for a sequence that shows something isn't a complete metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Hey I have to find a Cauchy-Sequence that converges in $(\mathbb{R} ,d_{|\cdot |})$ (absolute value as metric) and is still a Cauchy- Sequence with regards to a metric defined as $d(x,y):=|\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}|$ but doesn't converge in $(\mathbb{R},d)$. Has anyone got an idea or maybe a hint how i can proof that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ isn't a complete metric space?

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n = n$

Comment: It seems all you need is a sequence in $(\mathbb R,d)$ which is Cauchy w.r.t. $d$ but does not converge in that metric space.